# My html page structure breaks in Firefox but not Safari or Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

In the website I've just worked on, everything seems to be fine on Chrome and Safari, but my footer and a separator seem to jump randomly on Firefox.

The link is [www.wokrooms.be/en](http://www.wokrooms.be/en).

It happens to the photo block.

Comment: Please move your code here (only relevant part), don't share a link to your website.

Comment: What @Vadim means is that we want questions here that will remain useful for future readers. Given that you will fix your website in due course, this question will no longer be useful at that point, since readers will not be able to see what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your html change the photo_block section into

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-*"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/nikhilrajnair/pen/mwgzQW

As per Bootstrap Official documentation it's not good to place container class and col- class in same div.
for more visit [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved the problem